# How to compare the key of two buttons

Tags: flutter, function, dart, button

I have two columns on the screen with 2 buttons each. Each button in the column has its own meaning. In another column there are buttons with the same values. I would like to find out when I click on a button from one column, and then from the other whether their values are the same or not.

```
   Row( 
    
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    
          children:[
          Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
             ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () =>_column1(1), 
               child: Text("1")),
              SizedBox(height: 40,),
             ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () =>_column1(2), 
                child: Text("2")),
                            ],
                          ),
    
          Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
             ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: ()=>_column2(2), 
               child: Text("2")),
              SizedBox(height: 40,),
             ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: ()=>_column2(1), 
                child: Text("1")),
                            ],
                          ),
        ]
        );
      }
```

I made it so that when you click on the button from the column, they pass the key to the function.

```
 onPressed: () =>_column1(1),
```

I made 2 functions for each of the columns accepting the transmitted key.

```
  _column1 (int keyColumn1){
  int key1ForUnion;
  key1ForUnion = keyColumn1;
 return key1ForUnion;
}

_column2 (int keyColumn2){
  int key2ForUnion;
  key2ForUnion = keyColumn2;
  return key2ForUnion;
}
```

I also made a function that compares the received values and outputs a print whether they are equal or not

```
_unionKeyFunction(int key1ForUnion, int key2ForUnion){
  if( key1ForUnion == key2ForUnion ) {
     print("Equal");
  }
  else {
    print("Not equal");
  }
}
```

But I do not know how to make this function run every time I click on the buttons, because now when I click on them, I perform the functions of transferring their key. Could you help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice way is you need real primary-key to identify each button so we can process or define it later.

example:

```
String valueBtn1,valueBtn2,valueBtn3,valueBtn4 = "nothing";

ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {
//you may need setstate if you want to render the changes to UI
valueBtn1 = "clicked";
keyProcessor();
}, 
child: Text("1")),

do it to other button like this button1...


keyProcessor () {
  if( btn1 == btn2 ) {
     print("btn 1 and 2 is Equal");
  }
  else {
    print("Not equal");
  }

  if( btn1 == btn2 && btn3 == btn4 ) {
     print("btn 1x2 and btn3x4 is Equal");
  }
  else {
    print("Not equal");
  }

}
```

now you just need to implement this algorithm and edit the logic as you need